# Accessing implicit parameters explicitly at runtime

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

I'm trying to access an implicit parameter for a generic type. Scala is able to find the implicit just fine in the straightforward case by calling a method with an explicit generic type, such as with `printGenericType[Person]` below.

However, if I create a `TypeTag[Person]` and pass it to `printGenericTypeGivenTypeTag`, Scala is unable to find the implicit parameter.

```
case class Person(name: String)
case class Animal(age: Int)
implicit val p = Person("cory")
implicit val a = Animal(2)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  // Can find the implicit Person, prints "Hello Person(cory)"
  printGenericType[Person]

  // Can find the implicit Animal, prints "Hello Animal(2)"
  printGenericType[Animal]

  // See comment below
  printNamedType("Person")
  printNamedType("Animal")
}

def printGenericType[T](implicit t: T) = {
  println(s"Hello $t")
}

def printGenericTypeGivenTypeTag[T](typeTag: TypeTag[T])(implicit t: T) = {
  println(s"Hello $t")
}

def printNamedType[T](name: String) = {
  val typetag: TypeTag[T] = getTypeTag[T](name)

  // Cannot find the implicit of type T, compiler error
  printGenericTypeGivenTypeTag(typetag)
}

def getTypeTag[T](name:String): TypeTag[T] = ... //Implementation irrelevant
```

If I understand correctly, Scala locates implicit parameters at compile time, so it makes sense that it can't find an implicit parameter for the generic type `T` at compile time.

However, I know that an implicit instance of `T` does exist. Is it possible to rewrite `printGenericTypeGivenTypeTag` in such a way as to find the implicit value for `T`? At runtime, the method has access to the actual type of `T`, so it seems it should be able to locate an implicit parameter of the same type that is in scope.

For the curious, the reasoning behind this is to avoid this:

```
name match {
  case "Person" => printGenericType[Person]
  case "Animal" => printGenericType[Animal]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To answer the question**

You're not really wanting to pass the `T` implicitly, but rather the `TypeTag`, and not the `T`. Here's what I mean, and you're probably better off with an implicit value class.

```
implicit class GenericPrinter[T](val obj: T) extends AnyVal {
  def printGenericType()(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = {
    // do stuff with the tag
    Console.println("Hello $obj")
  }
}
val x: Person = Person(...)
x.printGenericType
```

**Now solving the real problem**

If you are trying to print case classes, I'd probably go down the implicit macro route for added convenience. It's really trivial to write up a macro that does this for us, e.g output a debug string based on all the constructor params of an arbitrary `case class`.

```
trait DeepPrinter[T <: Product with  Serializable] {

  /**
    * Prints a deeply nested debug string for a given case class.
    * This uses implicit macros to materialise the printer type class.
    * In English, when we request for an implicit printer: DeepPrinter[T],
    * the pre-defined compile time macro will generate this method for us
    * based on the fields of the given case class.
    *
    * @param sep A separator to use to delimit the rows in a case class.
    * @return A fully traced debug string so we can see how a case class looks like.
    */
  def debugString(sep: String = "\n"): String
}

object DeepPrinter {
  implicit def deepPrinter[T <: Product with Serializable] = macro DeepPrinterImpl.deepPrinterImpl[T]
}
```

And the macro is pretty trivial, looks kind of like this.

```
import language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@macrocompat.bundle
class DeepPrinterImpl(val c: blackbox.Context) {

  import c.universe._

  object CaseField {
    def unapply(symbol: TermSymbol): Option[(Name, Type)] = {
      if (symbol.isVal && symbol.isCaseAccessor) {
        Some(symbol.name -> symbol.typeSignature)
      } else {
        None
      }
    }
  }

  def fields(tpe: Type): Iterable[(Name, Type)] = {
    tpe.decls.collect { case CaseField(nm, tpeSn) => nm -> tpeSn }
  }

  def materialize[T : c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Expr[DeepPrinter[T]] = {
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
    val (names, types) = fields(tpe).unzip

    // change the package name to the correct one here!
    val tree = q"""
       new com.bla.bla.DeepPrinter[$tpe] {
         def debugString(sep: String = "\n") = Seq(..$names).mkString(sep)
       }
     """
    c.Expr[DeepPrinter[T]](tree)
  }
}
```